# How to retrieve the auto increment field name from a table?

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

I'm writing a function that gets the name of the AutoIncrement field in any given table

```
public sub GetID(ByVal tblName As String) As String
    Dim rs as RecordSet
    Dim fld as field

    For each fld in rs.Fields
        if fld.type = 'autoIncrement?'
            Exit for
        End If
    Next fld
    GetID = fld.Name
End Sub
```

I tried looking online but I couldn't find a dao field type for AutoIncrement. I noticed there is a type called DbGuid That seems to have something to do with this, but I can't figure out what it is. I  Also saw other sql DBMS that have a function for this sort of thing, but I couldn't find such a function in MS Access.

It is a big database and I don't know what the AutoIncrement field's name might be. So I can't do a instr(fieldname, "id") or something like that, to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attributes field can be a combination of a few values that become one total value see: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197380.aspx) and [MSDN Forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/identify-autonumber-field-in-vba/d126f827-8578-4e28-85a1-eea2e0472cd3?db=5&auth=1)

I could not get dbUpdateableField to print out a value for any field but apparently it is 32.

```
Attribute: dbAutoIncrField    Long: 16      Binary: 0000000000010000
Attribute: dbDescending       Long: 1       Binary: 0000000000000001
Attribute: dbFixedField       Long: 1       Binary: 0000000000000001
Attribute: dbHyperlinkField   Long: 32768   Binary: 1000000000000000
Attribute: dbSystemField      Long: 8192    Binary: 0010000000000000
Attribute: dbUpdateableField  Long: 0       Binary: 
Attribute: dbVariableField    Long: 2       Binary: 0000000000000010
```

So since the field is a total your standard autoNum field will 17 for being `dbAutoIncrField=16`, and `dbFixedField=1` so you could check `fld.Attributes` for a value of 17.  The AND according to the linked post performs a bitwise And returning true if there is a one in the proper position.

The result of `fld.Attributes` for your auto ID field is: `Name: AutoID Attributes: 17 Binary: 0000000000010001` so you have a 1 in the position of `dbAutoIncrField` and a 1 in the position of the `dbFixedField`

```
Private Function AutoNumberField(tableName As String) As String
     Dim dbs As DAO.Database
     Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
     Dim fld As DAO.Field

     Set dbs = CurrentDb
     Set tdf = dbs.TableDefs(tableName)
     For Each fld In tdf.fields
         If fld.Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
             AutoNumberField = fld.name
             Exit Function
         End If
     Next fld
End Function
```

Comment: Can you explain a little? what is `if fld.attributes` for?

Comment: @rosa There is a bit more explanation.